# Simple JWT Auth using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to do a simple JWT Authentication using only JQuery. I have already tested the backend with postman and everything seems to work in there.

Here's how my frontend code looks like

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var token = ''
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/authenticate',
      data: { name: name , password: password },
      success: function(resultData){
        var token = resultData.token;
        // console.log(token);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/memberinfo',
          headers: {"Authorization": token},
          success: function(data){
             $(location).attr('href', '/memberinfo')
          }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

so when I get redirected to the memberinfo page it shows me I am unauthorised. Not quite sure if I am doing the Ajax calls properly. Would be really helpful if some one could direct me the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simple use case just retrieve a token in the login request response and save it to the localStorage or sessionStorage. Then use the token from the localStorage inside every request header.
Please, have a look at an example code here.

https://github.com/chaofz/jquery-jwt-auth

On the other hand that is not secure to store a token in these storages as it is not protected from XSS attacks.

You better store token in cookies and check your cookies policies to prevent CSRF attack.

Please read more [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)

Comment: Storing jwt tokens on local storage is not recommended, your application will be vulnerable to XSS attacks.
Take a look at this article:  https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Answer (score 2):

i may be wrong, but a quick look of your code it might be because you set the api call for `GET request` and your client page the same url `/memberinfo`. your test result using `Postman` is working and also you are properly redirected to the `/memberinfo` upon success validation, however, since you are redirected to the same `/memberinfo` url and your browser didn't send `headers: {"Authorization": token}` you received `unauthorised` result.
try to make the api call url different with the client member page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add word "Bearer":

```
headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}, // note the space after Bearer
```